# Should servers exit with 0 or 1 in case of caught errors?

Tags: microservices, node.js, error-handling, kubernetes

What is the best practice in case a service has an error which we caught and handled?

Do we exit code 1 or 0?

Comment: Depends. Is there any other process handling this 0 or 1?

Comment: And why restrict yourself to `0` or `1`?

Comment: @Laiv It sounds like a good question but I'm not sure what do you mean.

Comment: @PhilipKendall sounds good. What is the best practice?

Comment: Maybe it's relevant, I'm working with k8s.

Comment: The questions is, If there's any other program handling the exit value. If not, doesn't matter. if yes, you might be interested in O.S exit codes to make the handler to behave in one or another way. As @PhilipKendall suggests, there're more than 0 and 1.

Answer (score 9):

A *service* that has caught *and handled* an error should not exit at all.

Otherwise, an exit code 0 indicates success, which for a service would be appropriate as the result of an orderly shutdown request.

If the exit is caused by an error, then any code other than 0 is appropriate, and different codes may be used to indicate different error conditions, but that is something that typically makes sense only for command line programs that are used in scripts, which services typically aren't.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a software that shall work automatically by itself on the background, or is it something a user will be executing?

In the first case you will want the program to never exit. To recover from any error as gracefully as possible, and log any unrecoverable one in a way that would be noticeable to the user.

In the second case exiting with code 1 (error) as soon as posible makes sense.